# mongoose ^6.0.12 findandupdate on models with required fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have updated my mongoose to version 6.0.12 but since that all usually workings findoneandupdate operations on models that have required fields and other validations rules stopped working

```
 try {
    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.userId,
      { $set : {picture: "./uploads/profile/" + fileName}},
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true},
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        else return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
  }
```

```
onst userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    pseudo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minLength: 3,
      maxLength: 55,
      unique: true,
      trim: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validate: [isEmail],
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 1024,
      minlength: 6
    },
    picture: {
      type: String,
      default: "./uploads/profile/random-user.png"
    },
    bio :{
      type: String,
      max: 1024,
    },
    followers: {
      type: [String]
    },
    following: {
      type: [String]
    },
    likes: {
      type: [String]
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I got this errors just after the updrade

> **"originalStack": "Error\n    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (C:\Users\amen\NODE\mern-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n
> at
> C:\Users\amen\NODE\mern-project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:279:20\n
> at _next
> (C:\Users\amen\NODE\mern-project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:103:16)\n
> at
> C:\Users\amen\NODE\mern-project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:508:38\n
> at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)"**

thank you in advance

Regards